# How to automatically resize a MarkerView created from xib

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-charts

I create marker from xib layout but it doesn't resize based on label length:

[image]

My marker class:

```swift
class MyMarker: MarkerView {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var lblValue: UILabel!
    
    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        // centering on top of bar
        self.offset.x = -self.frame.size.width / 2.0
        self.offset.y = -self.frame.size.height - 7.0
    }
    
    override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
        lblValue.text = String(entry.y)
    }
}
```

I did a little digging inside the IOS-Charts lib and found an interesting feature - although a marker can be created from xib (whose content is a view), the marker itself is not added to the view hierarchy. Instead, the content of the view is simply drawn on the chart canvas.

If we look at `MarkerView`, we will notice that it is just a convenient wrapper. Rendering on the chart occur in the `draw(context:point:)` method, which is defined in the `IMarker` protocol. That is, **`MarkerView` is not added to the view hierarchy**.

It seems to me that this may be the reason why the `MarkerView`'s constraints are not recalculated. I tried to force `MarkerView` to recalculate them but with no success:

```swift
override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    lblValue.text = String(entry.y)
    layoutSubviews() // doesn't work
    updateConstraints() // doesn't work
    subviews.forEach() { // even that doesn't work!
        $0.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

I even tried to resize the view bounds (and added a green background for clarity), but this did not force the constraints to be recalculated:

```swift
override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    lblValue.text = String(entry.y)

    bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY, width: 200, height: bounds.height)
    frame = bounds
    backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    layoutSubviews() // doesn't work
    updateConstraints() // doesn't work
    subviews.forEach() { // even that doesn't work!
        $0.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

**Question is** how to recalculate `MarkerView` constraints? And best of all - not by hand. After all, somehow the `MarkerView` calculates the correct constraints when initializing from xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed possible to recalculate view constants, even if it is not included in the hierarchy. In the case for IOS-Charts, it will look like this:

```swift
override func refreshContent(entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    lblValue.text = String(entry.y)
    
    // Recalculate marker sized based on lblValue width
    setNeedsLayout()
    layoutIfNeeded()

    // ...
}
```